Studio 3T for MongoDB installation failed during Login/Registration
When I was trying to install Studio 3T, the product needs registration. However, the registration request does not work.
I am trying to install Studio 3T (studio-3t-x64) for MongoDB on my laptop. I downloaded Studio 3T for MongoDB and installed it on my Windows (11) Laptop. When starting the application, in the pop-up window:

EULA: click "I agree" with the EULA. then click "next"
Production activation, click "Next"
Login/Registration. Click "Next". A browser tab was opened with the following URL: https://s3t-auth.studio3t.com/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://auth.studio3t.com/authorize-post&authorization_code=XXXXXXXXXXX&state=XXXXXXXXXXX
Then the browser shows "Loading ...." and then stops there and I can't go further to register the product.


I had the above issue when I tried to install Studio ST on my laptop. If you can help to solve the issue it will be great. Don't understand you want to vote down on it.

We're sorry to hear this. Can we please ask if you can try to use the browser in incognito/ private browsing mode to see if this helps? If not, please contact us via our support page and we can look into this for you.

Thank you for the suggestion. I tried Edge the problem is gone!
